# how Angular keyup event handling helps updating reference variable's value

Tags: angular, binding, interpolation, keyup

I'm new in Angular and I saw this piece of code in angular documents:

```
 <input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
```

No matter what is written in keyup event handling block, it just should be handled to the box.value get updated and string interpolation in next line, {{box.value}}, work properly. I was wondering how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has already been clarified in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable) clearly.

> **This won't work at all unless you bind to an event.**
>
> Angular updates the bindings (and therefore the screen) only if the
> app does something in response to asynchronous events, such as
> keystrokes. This example code binds the keyup event to the number 0,
> the shortest template statement possible. While the statement does
> nothing useful, it satisfies Angular's requirement so that Angular
> will update the screen.

Also from the docs.

> The template is completely self contained. It doesn't bind to the
> component, and the component does nothing.

So if you aren't explicitly telling Angular to check for changes in values (using `keyup` event here), it wouldn't care about the template reference variable `#box`.

Comment: you're right @Michael D thank you, I've been missing that part of document :)